# Querying a database would use tempdb files or database log file?

Tags: sql-server, logfile

I am new to SQL Server and have a basic question: querying SQL Server

For ex : `databasetest` would use and fill its database log file (`databasetest_log`) or `tempdbs'` primary or log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database transaction log records modifications to support commit and rollback. `SELECT` queries do not use the database log since these do not modify data.

`SELECT` queries might use tempdb (data and log) depending on the execution plan (e.g. for sorting) or for a row-versioning isolation level to provide read-consistency.

DDL (e.g. CREATE statements) and data modification statements (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `MERGE`) will use the database transaction log. These might also use tempdb similarly to `SELECT` statements depending on the execution plan or if row-versioning is needed.